Merge conflict error using kidff3 as mergetool
enter image description hereMerging:sample-project/sample-project/index.html
mv: cannot move 'sample-project/sample-project/index.html' to './sample-project/sample-project/index_BACKUP_2001.html': Device or resource busycp: cannot stat './sample-project/sample-project/index_BACKUP_2001.html': No such file or directoryNormal merge conflict for 'sample-project/sample-project/index.html':{local}: modified file{remote}: modified file
as part of my assignment in devops course , Merged branch 1 ,2 master (merge conflicts should arise). Merge conflicts should be resolved by kdiff3. I got above err
or and doesn't execute anything here after. Execited commands in gitbash .Please guide me.
We have to Install a merge tool of our choice and resolve the merge conflict using git mergetool command. i tried opening kdiff3 app , searched in youtube but understand this error.
